# JDBC result set from an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

What does oracleClose() and oracleCloseQuery() do in sqlj.runtime.ExecutionContext.OracleContext.

Since we upgraded jdbc driver jar to `ojdbc5.jar` with the `oracleClose()` in the finally block we get the below exception when using `resultset.next()` and not with `oracleCloseQuery()`. Is it safe to use `oracleCloseQuery()`. The database is Oracle 11g and WAS 6.1.X.X. Appreciate your response.
Here is the error message :

> java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement: next
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:197)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:269)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:205)
>   at com.westgroup.pubsvc.rms.models.ResultSetSRC.getNextResult(ResultSetSRC.java:112)

Answer (score 6):

The exception is telling you that the `Statement` which has returned this `ResultSet` is been closed while you're attempting to iterate over the `ResultSet`. This indicates that you're using `ResultSet` *outside* the `try` block where the `Statement` is been executed and that you're probably using the `ResultSet` as return value of the method. This is a **bad practice**.

I'd suggest you to rewrite your JDBC code so that the `ResultSet` is been processed in the very same `try` block as the `Statement` is been executed, or that the methods returns something like as `List<Entity>` instead of a `ResultSet`.

Here's a kickoff example of the correct JDBC idiom:

```
public List<Entity> list() throws SQLException {
    // Declare resources.
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    try {
        // Acquire resources.
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement("SELECT id, name, value FROM entity");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        // Gather data.
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Entity entity = new Entity(); 
            entity.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            entity.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            entity.setValue(resultSet.getInteger("value"));
            entities.add(entity);
        }
    } finally {
        // Close resources in reversed order.
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    // Return data.
    return entities;
}
```

By the way, you don't need Oracle JDBC driver specific classes/methods here. It's all just `java.sql.*`. This way you keep the JDBC code portable among databases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The mothod returns Resultset and is being used later after the finally block is executed which is not a good practice but worked with Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0". And this code is Jpublisher generated java code from the stored procedure. So does this mean we need to change the stored procedure.

Comment: I am not sure what JPublisher is all doing, but passing around the `ResultSet` outside the methods like that is a bad idea. You don't need to change the stored procedure. You just need to map the `ResultSet` to a `List<Entity>` as demonstrated in the answer.